# Is there any difference between instances of EntityManager and QueryRunner in TypeORM + nest.js + jest.js?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Would it be any difference between the instances of `EntityManager` and `QueryRunner` in TypeORM + nest.js + jest.js?

```
import { Connection, EntityManager, getConnection, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

const connection: Connection = getConnection('default');
connection.createEntityManager();
const entityManager: EntityManager = connection.manager;
const queryRunner: QueryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();

await queryRunner.query(`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 2048`);
const groupConcatMaxLen = await queryRunner.query(`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len'`);
const groupConcatMaxLen2 = await entityManager.query(`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len'`);
console.log(groupConcatMaxLen);
console.log(groupConcatMaxLen2);

entityManager.query(`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len'`);
queryRunner.query(`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len'`);
```

Output:

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    Variable_name: 'group_concat_max_len',
    Value: '2048'
  }
]

[
  RowDataPacket {
    Variable_name: 'group_concat_max_len',
    Value: '1024'
  }
]
```